# Set URL with firstname.lastname

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried to use `.htaccess` RewriteRules, but it wont work like I thought it would work.

My RewriteRules:

```
RewriteRule ^login?$ login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^me profile.php?user-id=me [QSA,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-\s]+).([A-Za-z-\s]+)$ profile.php?user-id=$1.$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^settings?$ settings.php [NC,L]
```

My Problem is if the user types the server URL (`localhost/box4/`) it will show `index.php`.

My mention was to get the username; example: `john.doe`

Like in Facebook, it should separate the username: `firstname.lastname` (separated by a dot)

I decided to generate the username from PHP:

```
foreach(explode(".",$_GET['user-id']) as $val1){
    $userName .= $val1." ";
}
$userName = ucwords($userName);
```

I want that it should not use `index.php`. Wrong result would happen: `firstname` = `index` and `lastname` = `php`

What can I change to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(login|settings)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^me/?$ profile.php?user-id=me [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^index [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-\s]+)\.([A-Za-z-\s]+)$ profile.php?user-id=$1.$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: For now your answer woks, thanks. :) I also understand your answer (this is important for me) :D